# How to better write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables here at work, and need to transform the data to look a bit different. For arguments sake, here are the two main tables I am working with.

```
[dbo].[Contracts](
    [ContractId] [int]
    <Some Other Fields>
)

[dbo].[ContractVehicles](
    [ContractVehicleId] [int]
    [ContractId] [int] **(FK to Contracts)**,
    [VehicleDescription] [varchar],
    [Price] [int]   
)
```

As you can see, there are contracts and contract vehicles. A contract can have many vehicles associated to it.

I would like a table that looks like the following:

```
[dbo].[ContractSummaries](
    [ContractSummaryId] [int] **(just this table's seed)**,
    [ContractId] [int]
    [VehicleType1Desc] [varchar],
    [VehicleType1Count] [int],
    [VehicleType1TotalPrice] [int],
    [VehicleType2Desc] [varchar],
    [VehicleType2Count] [int],
    [VehicleType2TotalPrice] [int],
    [VehicleType3Desc] [varchar],
    [VehicleType3Count] [int],
    [VehicleType3TotalPrice] [int]
)
```

Basically, I'd like a table that lists a contract and up to the first 3 vehicle types associated with that contract, along with # of vehicles of that type, and the total price for that type.

To achieve this, I have written the query below. Is there a more succinct and efficient way to write this? **Please note**, *none of the structure's or queries I've provided are the actual queries, and I may have syntactical errors in these representations. I apologize for that, and hope these examples succeed in demonstrating my intent.*

```
SELECT
    ContractId,
    (
        SELECT
            VehicleDescription
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 1
    ) VehicleType1Desc,
    (
        SELECT
            NumVehicle
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 1
    ) VehicleType1Count,
    (
        SELECT
            TotalVehicleTypePrice
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 1
    ) VehicleType1TotalPrice,
    (
        SELECT
            VehicleDescription
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 2
    ) VehicleType2Desc,
    (
        SELECT
            NumVehicle
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 2
    ) VehicleType2Count,
    (
        SELECT
            TotalVehicleTypePrice
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 2
    ) VehicleType2TotalPrice,
    (
        SELECT
            VehicleDescription
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 3
    ) VehicleType3Desc,
    (
        SELECT
            NumVehicle
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 3
    ) VehicleType3Count,
    (
        SELECT
            TotalVehicleTypePrice
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(VehicleDescription), ContractId ASC) as rownumber,
                VehicleDescription,
                COUNT(v.VehicleDescription) NumVehicle,
                SUM(Price) TotalVehicleTypePrice
            FROM
                Contracts c INNER JOIN ContractVehicles v on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
            WHERE
                c.ContractId = cOuter.ContractId
            GROUP BY
                v.ContractID,
                v.VehicleDescription
        ) countTable
        WHERE
            rowNumber = 3
    ) VehicleType3TotalPrice,
FROM
    Contracts outerC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think that you can simplify the query.  The following aggregates the vehicle information to get the `count`, `price`, and "sequence number" for each vehicle in each contract.  The contract information is then joined in, and the result aggregated:

```
select c.ContractSummaries, c.ContractSummaryId,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then VehicleDescription end) as VehicleType1Desc,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then NumV end) as VehicleType1Count,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Price end) as VehicleType1Price,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then VehicleDescription end) as VehicleType2Desc,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then NumV end) as VehicleType2Count,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then Price end) as VehicleType2Price,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then VehicleDescription end) as VehicleType3Desc,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then NumV end) as VehicleType3Count,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then Price end) as VehicleType3Price
from Contracts c join
     (select cv.ContractId, cv.VehicleDescription, count(*) as NumV,
             sum(Price) as Price,
             row_number() over (partition by ContractId, VehicleDescription
                                order by count(*) desc
                               ) seqnum
      from ContractVehicles cv
      group by cv.ContractId, cv.VehicleDescription
     ) v
     on c.ContractId = v.ContractId
group by c.ContractId, c.ContractSummaries, c.ContractSummaryId;
```

I am unclear on the relationship between `ContractId` and `ContractSummaryId` -- your description of what you want is "vehicles per contract" so that is what this does.  A query that returns "vehicles per contract summary" might be a bit different.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this makes things clearer in my mind. Not sure why I decided i needed to use subqueries. One thing I'm not clear about in your example though, is what max() accomplishes on each column in the select. After I translate this into actual queries tomorrow morning, I'll be sure to make this as correct.

Comment: @DavidGutierrez You could also use MIN instead of MAX. This is a trick due to the group by clause. Else this query would not be executable.

Comment: After adjusting the row_number() partition to not include vehicle description, this worked great. Thanks again.